# Div overflows table height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a web page where I want the table to be 90% of the height, but when I make a div with overflow-y set to scrolling, it becomes larger anyways, and makes the table too high. Help please?

```
.header {
    background-color:#CCCCDD;
}
table {
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    border-color:#333333;
}
body {
    background-image:url(BG.jpg);
    background-attachment:fixed;
    font-family: calibri;
    z-index: -1;
}
#main {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #666;
    top: 25px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #EEE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #EEE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #EEE;
    width: 800px;
    height: 90%;
}
#commandDiv {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #2c2c2c;
    background-color: #8F8F8F;
}
.command {
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.commandDesc {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#imageDiv {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #333;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #8F8F8F;
}
#commandTR {
    height: 100%;
}
#siteDesc {
    margin: 12px;
}
#secondaryTitle {
    font-size: 40px;
}
p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
#origin {
    padding-top: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#tournaments {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can we see a sample of the html as well?

Comment: HTML code would help people replica and solve the problem. It might be that you can put the overflow-y on the main id.

Comment: The only element with `overflow-y:scroll` is the `#commandDiv`, but I can't see where you're trying to restrict its height? `overflow-y` by itself doesn't change anything about the height.